# How to display timepicker dialog when radiobutton is clicked?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display time picker dialog by using `showDialog(1);` when radio button is clicked. But i cannot display if i write onclick event for radio button. How to solv this problem? Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: please consider adding in code snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  RadioButton r;
  r.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener){

 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
 // add your dialog here
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

YOu follow the link to get to know about the date picker:
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-datepicker-dialog-example

you just have to replace the button date to the radio button, note the id used in the button should be same as that in the radio button.